# Improve drawing speed when ArcMap layout refreshes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, performance

I'm working with an 21x26" layout that contains ~ 20 callout graphics. Due to time constraints, I am unable to setup a custom label expression based on attributes and have to work with what I have.

Is there any way to improve ArcMap drawing performance OR force ArcMap not to redraw all graphics each time I perform any action? When working exclusively with data I normally pause the drawing or work in data view, but now I have the unfortunate pleasure of having to edit each callout individually.

Comment: Do you have any basemap layers (ie, pulling from network or internet) loaded? If so, turn them off. If you have any imagery layers, turning those off may help as well. That's not a terribly huge layout or excessive number of graphics, so I'm not sure why things would be slow for you unless there are other graphics/more complex layout. You can also set the dataframe to only draw as a preview to speed things up - properties, frame tab, check 'draft mode' box at bottom. How many data frames in the layout?

Comment: @ChrisW I have turned off all of my layers with the exception of a feature class point layer (it draws instantly if I switch to data view). I also have no idea why these callouts are causing so much trouble. Could map size be a part of the problem? I turned on "Draft mode" but it does not improve the performance. There is only one data frame.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by map size - mxd document file size? There are lots of things that can be stored in the mxd (including all the graphics) that can potentially slow the file down. I translated a couple of old map book documents that were like 45MB because of all the extra scripts and stuff that were loaded into them and they saved down to less than 1MB. Also if things are embedded in the mxd as opposed to just linked to (logos, etc). Could be a corrupted/ing mxd as well. Without the mxd at least to open and poke around in, I can't think of anything else to suggest.

Comment: Have you tried "lock labels" in the labeling toolbar? It may be struggling to place the labels, if you lock them it doesn't try to find the best location every time it just remembers where they are and puts them there.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson These aren't labels though as far as ArcMap is concerned, they are graphics (under add Text on the Drawing toolbar). I believe using labels would fix the issue but time was a factor.

Comment: How about snapping, if you're editing and there are a lot of potential features the snap cache needs to be built on each refresh, either turn snapping off if you don't need it or turn off the snaps you're not interested in (end, vertex, boundary).